# Node.js Nodemailer does not generate attachment content

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I'm trying to automate emails with nodemailer. The problem is that I can't get attachments to work. Here's a sample script

```
var mailOptions = {
    from: 'apples@gmail.com', // sender address
    to: newClient.a22, // list of receivers
    cc: managerEmail, // list of receivers
    bcc: financeEmail, // list of receivers
    subject: newClient.a4 + ' |' + monthofService +' | Revision ID: '+revisionId, // Subject line
    html: printoutfile.replace(/(\n)/g, '<br>'),
    attachments : [ {   // utf-8 string as an attachment
          fileName: 'check.txt',
          contents: 'checking that some attachments work...'
      }]

};
```

Everything works except for the attachment parts. Even the filename of the mailer

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its ***content*** not contents. Check the sample code on the nodemailer wesite http://www.nodemailer.com/

```
var mailOptions = {
    from: 'apples@gmail.com', // sender address
    to: newClient.a22, // list of receivers
    cc: managerEmail, // list of receivers
    bcc: financeEmail, // list of receivers
    subject: newClient.a4 + ' |' + monthofService +' | Revision ID:'+revisionId, // Subject line
    html: printoutfile.replace(/(\n)/g, '<br>'),
    attachments : [ {   // utf-8 string as an attachment
          fileName: 'check.txt',
          content: 'checking that some attachments work...'
       }]
};
```